# how to show fake directory using htaccess for image folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mode

I have a image folder and it has images uploaded by users in my website.

The image path was show like this in source code

```
/wp-content/uploads/1/49485_thumbnail.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/422/49480_thumbnail.jpg
```

I want to show like it was inside the fake folder "images"

```
/images/1/49485_thumbnail.jpg
/images/422/49480_thumbnail.jpg
```

Help me to create the RewriteRule to do this.

Comment: Did you see the preview how it showed before you posted?

Comment: Your looking for something like `RewriteRule ^/images/([a-zA-Z0-9\s\._-]+) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.htaccess` directory redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Op  wants to show the fake folder so R=301 Doesnt help here.

Comment: @Preveen Kumar thanks for your reply.... i used like you said but it is not changing the path . i am posting my htaccess entries below                              </br>                                                                                                                              <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @Praveen Kumar sir it is working. but if i view the page source it is showing the same old path not the new one. both links i tested in url it is showing image. but the view source is showing as /wp-content/uploads/1/49485_thumbnail.jpg not as images/1/49485_thumbnail.jpg

Comment: <img src='http://s32.postimg.org/8hll5gt3p/image_path.jpg' border='0' alt="image path" />

Comment: @mandi007 Did you check your database for entries like that? You need to edit post and update it again.